# Разница в использовании sockaddr_in и sockaddr_un?

Tags: c, unix, сокет, linux

В примерах кода вижу использование разных структур при инициализации сокетов: sockaddr_in и sockaddr_un. В описании функции bind указано, что

> The only purpose of this structure is to cast the structure pointer passed in addr in order to avoid compiler warnings.

Есть ли реальное различие?

Answer (score 2):

`socketaddr_un` используется при создании сокетов для общения процессов на одной машине (т.н. Unix domain), а `socketaddr_in` - для общения через сеть Интернет по протоколу IPv4.